# gplus and twitter(integrated) loading in arabic language always-ios

Tags: localization, ios9, arabic, google-signin, twitter-fabric

I have integrated gplus and twitter login into my ios app and i need to use Arabic and english language for it.So for that i used HMLocalization third party framework.But even my language is in English type,the twitter and gplus interface changes into Arabic version as the images given below.So please help me to restore the language into English Version.

[image]

Comment: i found the solution .i juz removed the googleplus sdk from pod and cleared the simulator. then again added pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk'
 and installed pod...so its working now..